# Github: Creating an inter-repository pull request?

Tags: git, github, version-control

The normal github workflow makes it easy to generate and process a pull request between two branches in a repository.

How do I create a github pull request that references a forked repo?

Context:  I've forked a repo, made some changes, and want to submit the changes to the original author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push a commit to your forked repo and your forked repo gets ahead of the original repo, you will get an option to create a pull request as shown below:[image].

Just click the button to create the pull request and the author of original repo will be notified of the pull -request